# Reinstalling an app after purging it

Tags: 18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04 I am trying to setup a Nextcloud server. Everything works but I was trying to connect with my public IP and there was a port forwarding issue. Never the less I fixed the issue and was just trying to make the Nextcloud secure with certbot.

Unfortunately I got an error, and in an attempt to fix it I uninstalled it Nextcloud. For some reason now when I'm trying to reinstall I keep getting errors that its "unable to fetch some of the archives".

To install the application (certbot) i used: `sudo apt install certbot`

And this is what comes up:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-ce rtbot/certbot_0.27.0-1~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb 
Could not resolve ‘gb.archive.ubun tu.com’ E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mis sing?
```

The "failed to fetch" error happened multiple times.
Oh and I have tried `sudo apt-get update`

But when i do `sudo apt-get update` the same error still occurs so its more of a issue with my apt install

Comment: I think we need more exact commands and full error messages. Please edit your question, and make use of the code formatting.

Comment: Is your software repository list up-to-date?   That package isn't the latest version for bionic (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-certbot) so either you need to `sudo apt update` & watch for any errors, or there is more detail you've not told us.

Comment: Try to wget one of this:

http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-certbot-apache/

http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-ceres/

(I think that the 1st would be the correct,idk if te certbot needs apache)

I looked into 
http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/

So maybe if the package isnt one of these two you could find it manually and install it using

    wget "url"

(i dont know how is really the command,but you can search a bit about it)

Comment: Trying to do sudo apt update also comes up with the same failed to fetch errors

Comment: Is `‘gb.archive.ubun tu.com’` a typo you made entering the question? Or is that space really in your sources?